# Uploading large video files directly to s3

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I have direct link to an `mp4` video file which is hosted somewhere, Is there any online API by which I can directly upload that file to `Amazon s3`, I have seen several codes that copies code from local / or same server to `Amazon s3`. Is there any way to copy large files to `Amazon s3` ? wondering about the thing as well if the php times out etc

[This doesn'help much in my case.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430693/uploading-large-hd-video-files-to-amazon-web-services-s3)

Comment: If your concern is that the MP4 is large and your internet connection is slow then you could spin up an EC2 instance (e.g. c4.8xlarge), wget the MP4 on to the EC2 instance, and then use the awscli to push the MP4 from there into S3. The EC2 instance will not cost much for an hour, and it probably has a higher bandwidth connection than you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, S3 isn't feature-rich like that. If you can't upload the file from your source, you must use an intermediary server to download or stream the file.